# React-Native 0.20 - setInterval not working as expected

Tags: react-native

Has anyone been able to get `setInterval` working as expected with React-Native? I am having very inconsistent results where:

1) The delay before execution does not match the `ms` delay set

2) Further executions after the initial one *do not always* occur, but sometimes do.

My interval code is simply in my component, as shown:

```
componentDidMount() {
   this.syncFunc = setInterval(() => {
      this.props.actions.syncState()
   }, 5000)
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.syncFunc)
}
```

I've also tried the [TimerMixin](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/timers.html#content) that is included in react-native, but I don't think it's supported much at this point. The code for that was similar:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.syncFunc = TimerMixin.setTimeout(() => {
        this.props.actions.syncState()
    , 5000)
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    TimerMixin.clearTimeout(this.syncFunc)
}
```

Appreciate any advice from others who've tinkered with this. Thanks!

Comment: I've set up an example [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/EDf5qA) and it seems to work fine. Can you check it out and see if there's any difference with yours ?

Comment: I noticed a weird behaviour once you start refreshing the app many times. Can you check if that's the case?

Comment: I'm facing similar issue. @G.Hamaide The link is broken :(